# How do I $match for specific value in json object in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I use MongoDB and I have lots of JSON objects in a column that look like that:

Address (column)

```
[{"type":"BILLING","firstname":"XXX","lastname":"XXX","street":"XXX","city":"XXX","postcode":"78311","countryCode":"PL"}]
```

I would like to use a $match function to only search for results that have "countryCode":"PL" in the object (so I want to filter results based on that criteria) because I also have different results from countries all over the world.

I tried to use:

```
{
   $match: {address:{$in:["PL"]}
}
```

but unfortunately, it doesn't work. It does work for non JSON objects but not in that case. I attach a picture for better understanding, I made sure not to include personal information[image].

Answer (score 2):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/dPCAHoeWRnB

You have to use `"address.countryCode"` to query nested data.

Read [Match Nested Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#specify-equality-match-on-a-nested-field)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "address.countryCode": { $in: [ "PL" ] } }
  }
])
```